# Overwrite data without generating new key/node

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to overwrite some data in my database. The structure is simple, being:

```
recipes {
  user_1{
    recipe_1{data}
    recipe_2{data}
  }
  user_2{
    recipe_1{data}
    recipe_2{data}
  }
}
```

I'm trying to update an item and overwrite it with any changes using this, where `recipe` is the new object with the updated data I'm trying to save, and `key` is the unique key generated for each item in the database. In the database itself the labels `recipe_1` and so on would be replaced with their unique keys. So this path should be just replacing the entire `recipe_2` instead of adding a new node.

```
firebase.database().ref('recipes/' + userID + "/" + key).set({ recipe });
```

So say I was attempting to update `user_1's` `recipe_2` with this, after going through, the database structure would then be:

```
data {
  user_1{
    recipe_1{data}
    recipe{
      recipe_2{data}
    }
  }
  user_2{
    recipe_1{data}
    recipe_2{data}
  }
}
```

How can I overwrite the item and keep the structure of the database the same while changing the contents of the recipe?

Comment: Try with `firebase.database().ref('recipes/' + userID + "/" + key).set(recipe);` Can you share what data are you updating ? value of `recipe` and `data` ?

Comment: @stud3nt Were the extra curly braces in my code creating a new node with the name `recipe` and tacking the data into it? Because removing those like you suggested actually fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes the extra `{}` was creating a new nested node into the key value. Are you able to update the value as per your requirement ?

Comment: @stud3nt Yes I was, thank you very much.

Comment: Great! I have added the answer below. Please upvote and mark it as an answer if it has helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the extra `{}` from your `set` function which is creating a new node in the key value you are trying to update.

Change your code to 
 `firebase.database().ref('recipes/' + userID + "/" + key).set(recipe);`